# SharedPref coming with old data

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I clear sharedpref
Run flutter clean

But when I build to release apk then install my real device sharedpref coming with old data. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this..? How you manage to clear the sharedpref..?

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear your app's data in your real device. To do that, go to

1. Settings
2. Apps (may vary depending on you android os)
3. Choose the app
4. Click clear data (you need to click storage and then click clear data in newer devices)

NB: flutter clean clears the build files not shared preferences. Shared preferences are stored on local device (like cookies in a website).

Alternatively, you can uninstall the current installation from your real device and install again.

Comment: But why I have to do this. I cant say my users to do that. I need to clear all caches and storage before build. I need clear build.

Comment: Do you users already have the app installed? Is your current build an update?

Comment: You can clear shared pref store programatically on startup

Comment: No even first time installed It comes with olda data.

Comment: That's is not possible unless you are setting these values explicitly somewhere in your code. Did clearing app data solve the issue?

Comment: If I clear the storage in android settings yeah its fixed. But this is the problem :D App coming with caches or what it called. This is not about the code because even I didnt start app only install it comes with old data.

Comment: That's technically not possible... Shared preference file that is written as runtime. Apps are not packed with shared preference files. Are you using some third party plugins? Can you share the link if so?